# How to deploy my bitbucket code easily to my production server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I got a private git repo on Bitbucket, i update it from my local repo. It works just fine.
But now my project is about to be done and i need to find a solution to deploy my code to the production server.

I look for a easy and fast solution but i did not find anything for bitbucket, all solution seems to be designed for github...

Of course i can connect to the serv and make a `git pull` but i really want to find something to automate this.

Do you know a service, a tool for that ?

Comment: Something like this? http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/

Comment: @user1615903 Yeah this looks good to me :)

Comment: this tutorial may help   https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/ruby-on-rails-deploy-on-engineyard-server/

Comment: i read that pulling directly into the web root is a bad idea as the .git files are available for hackers there. Eventually giving them access to your complete codebase

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally use choose [Dandelion](https://github.com/scttnlsn/dandelion).

It's really easy to install : `gem install dandelion` and easy to use, you just have to edit  dandelion.yml put your connection info there and then `dandelion deploy`!

Works fine, fully integrated with git and service agnostic :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea that there is a easy and fast solution to deploy your code is a lie - don't believe it. There are always things that you've missed, and there are always things that go wrong. So don't underestimate it or leave it as an afterthought.

You haven't given away anything about your application, so I can't give you specific details, but if you own your own server and are looking for a way of simplifying the deployment step, take a look at [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano). It's not only for rails apps, despite the fact that it works for these out of the box. I've used it on PHP projects with great success - it just takes a bit more setup.

If you're looking for a fully automated solution including hosting, you might like something like [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). However, this is dependent on your application, and what technology you've used.

Comment: It's a PHP project but i would like to find a "universal" solution, and yes i own the server :)

Comment: @x4vier in that case, my answer still stands. I've used both heroku and capistrano for PHP projects, where I've needed different levels on control.

Comment: Heroku can be a nice answer for test server nop ? I read somewhere that you can host Wordpress on it. I gotta check this.

Comment: @x4vier I've used heroku to deploy Wordpress before. It's fine, but it can't handle uploads - you need to use external storage like Amazon S3.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku It's a template for deploying WP on heroku, it allows uploads too :)

Answer (score 1):

Without the necessary of an external service, you can use the [Git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to automatically deploy your code to your server.

For example, you can copy your code using `rsync` or `scp` after each commit on the *master* branch.

Comment: Can I do this from a git hook on bitbucket? As in, is it possible that I put the logic to pull new code on remote within a hook, to deploy new code whenever new code is pushed?

Comment: @DivijSehgal You can either leverage a service like Travis CI or CircleCI for this, or you can subscribe to the BitBucket HTTP webhooks (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-hooks-776639836.html) and deploy the code manually from a server you've set up

Answer (score 0):

if its bitbucket , the first thing comes in mind is easy , scalable.
During my deployment of BitBucket , I did a preety big research and I used **Jelastic**.
Its been a while now and now I can confirm you that its super stable-

> Maven is a build automation and software comprehension tool which is
>   primarily used for Java programming. With Maven you can add any public
>   or private project to Jelastic and build it in the cloud. Jelastic
>   takes your application's source code directly from your version
>   control system (SVN or Git).

I will recommend to try Jelastic once for bitbucket implementation and compare.
More details can be found -

http://jelastic.com/docs/bitbucket-project-maven